# Same DataFrame.reindex code - different output

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, reindex

Good afternoon everyone,

I want to filter out from a DataFrame the columns that I am not interested in.
To do that - and since the columns could change based on user input (that I will not show here) - I am using the following code within my `offshore_filter` function:

```
# Note: 'df' is my DataFrame, with different country codes as rows and years as columns' headers

import datetime as d
import pandas as pd

COUNTRIES = [
        'EU28', 'AL', 'AT', 'BE', 'BG', 'CY', 'CZ', 'DE', 'DK', 'EE', 'EL',
        'ES', 'FI', 'FR', 'GE', 'HR', 'HU', 'IE', 'IS', 'IT', 'LT', 'LU', 'LV',
        'MD', 'ME', 'MK', 'MT', 'NL', 'NO', 'PL', 'PT', 'RO', 'SE', 'SI', 'SK',
        'TR', 'UA', 'UK', 'XK'

YEARS = list(range(2005, int(d.datetime.now().year)))

def offshore_filter(df, countries=COUNTRIES, years=YEARS):
    # This function is specific for filtering out the countries
    # and the years not needed in the analysis

    # Filter out all of the countries not of interest
    df.drop(df[~df['country'].isin(countries)].index, inplace=True)

    # Filter out all of the years not of interest
    columns_to_keep = ['country', 'country_name'] + [i for i in years]
    temp = df.reindex(columns=columns_to_keep)
    df = temp  # This step to avoid the copy vs view complication

    return df
```

When I pass a `years` list of integers, the code works well and filters the DataFrame by taking only the columns in the `years` list.

However, if the DataFrame's column headers are strings (e.g. `'2018'` instead of `2018`), changing `[i for i in years]` into `[str(i) for i in years]` doesn't work, and I have columns of Nan's (as the `reindex` [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html#pandas.DataFrame.reindex) states).

**Can you help me spot me why?**

Comment: Is it possible to add an example dataset of a couple of rows so we can test ourselves?

Comment: Thank @erfan for the answer. I uploaded two example files in [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Ab6MnTcCrZ9cwOAYFtPjj5bi4Ub6yTJ3).

Pay attention: one is pure Excel file, the other a TSV one. The one not working (e.g. the one with the column headers as strings) is the TSV one.